# There is no syntax highlighting in Discussions

Tags: bug, status-planned, syntax-highlighting, discussions-space

On main site Q&A, syntax highlighting works as soon as you add a relevant tag to the question like [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), or a language hint before the code block:

```php
// This comment is grey. Other colors are below:
function addNumbers(int $a, int $b): int {
    return $a + $b;
}
```

On Discussions, there is no syntax highlighting no matter what you do. See this [example top-level Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions/77687558/type-hinting-in-php) and this [example reply](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions/77094362/77094969). However, in the (unlinked?) revision history ([reply revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77094969/revisions)), the proper syntax highlighting is shown—apparently they even used a language hint.

Comment: I see that the code seems to wrapped with three backticks and "php" and not three backticks and space "lang-php", Could that be part of the problem? I can't edit discussions so I can't check this myself, but I can see the most recent edit of tthe first link you gave

Comment: @PeterJames It shouldn't need to be wrapped with anything since the PHP tag itself is marked as "Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-php".

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue caused [in full.en.js](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=efb11489a333). This cannot be corrected by any changes to markdown. HighlightJS is not even being loaded on these pages.

There is some conditional logic in the `styleCodeBlocks` function that determines whether or not the syntax highlighter needs to be loaded based on the presence of code blocks.

The current selector that is being used is:

```js
$(".js-post-body pre code, .js-wmd-preview pre code, .js-md-preview pre code, .js-style-code pre code")
```

This, unfortunately, give a particularly poor user experience because the revision history *and* editor both have matching selectors which causes HLJS to be loaded. However, the discussions page structure results in no matching selections and by extension HLJS is not loaded at all on the page.

Adding the selector `.js-discussion .s-prose pre code` will locate the code blocks in the top level discussion and `.js-reply pre code` will locate code blocks in the replies. After these two are added highlighting will function as expected.

```js
$(".js-discussion .s-prose pre code, .js-reply pre code, .js-post-body pre code, .js-wmd-preview pre code, .js-md-preview pre code, .js-style-code pre code")
```

A working example ([modified from full.en.js](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=efb11489a333)) could look like:

> ```js
> function getDefaultCodeblockLanguageOverride() {
>     // pull lang from hidden div rendered server side via @HtmlUtil.CodeblockLangDiv call
>     return $('#js-codeblock-lang').text() || null;
> }
>
> function styleCodeBlocks() {
>     // if jtab is present (guitar tab support), don't color any code blocks
>     if (typeof jtab !== "undefined") {
>         jtab.renderimplicit();
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // keep track of if we need to even need to load the syntaxhighlighter
>     var detectedCodeBlock = false;
>
>     // check every `pre code` block (in a post, discussion, discussion reply, or editor preview) and set the language classes as needed
>     $(".js-discussion .s-prose pre code, .js-reply pre code, .js-post-body pre code, .js-wmd-preview pre code, .js-md-preview pre code, .js-style-code pre code").parent().each(function () {
>
>         // explicitly specify the classes we're using in one spot for reuse
>         var highlightClass = "s-code-block";
>         // TODO can't change to `codeblock-override` without rebaking posts...
>         var overrideClass = "prettyprint-override";
>
>         // if this block has a specifically overridden language, use it
>         if ($(this).hasClass(overrideClass)) {
>             $(this).removeClass(overrideClass).addClass(highlightClass);
>             detectedCodeBlock = true;
>         }
>
>         // if there is no specific language set, try to use the set default class
>         if (!$(this).hasClass(highlightClass)) {
>             var defaultLang = getDefaultCodeblockLanguageOverride();
>             if (defaultLang) {
>                 $(this)
>                     .addClass(defaultLang)
>                     .addClass(highlightClass);
>                 detectedCodeBlock = true;
>             }
>         }
>     });
>
>     
>     // if we detected any code blocks that need styling, init our highlighter
>     if (detectedCodeBlock) {
>         StackExchange.using("highlightjs", function () {
>             // highlightjs.initHighlighting highlights all `pre code`s by default and requires the lang class to be on the `code` block.
>             // We only want to highlight our `pre.s-code-block`s specifically and our lang class is on the `pre` block.
>             // Highlight each of these manually while skipping already highlighted blocks with the added hljs class
>             $("pre.s-code-block code:not(.hljs)").each(function () {
>
>                 // Exclude code blocks that are direct descendents of the stacks editor contenteditable div
>                 if ($(this).parents('.js-editor').length != 0) {
>                     return;
>                 }
>                 StackExchange.highlightjs.instance.highlightElement(this);
>             });
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

This could easily be turned into a UserScript by adding `StackExchange.ready(styleCodeBlocks);`and wrapping in an IIFE for those who would like the temporary fix.